# how to know possible exceptions when using try catch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is a bad practice to catch exceptions without a specific type and using for example `System.Net.Exception`

Do I have to dig into the msdn manual to see the possible exception types each time I'm going to catch an error. Or is there any way in the IDE to let me see this quickly.

Currently I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition

```
 try
 {
    using (WebClient goog = new WebClient()) 
    {
       goog.DownloadString("http://google.com");
    } 
 }
 catch(Exception E)
 {
    saveLog("methodname", E.Message);
 }
```

**EDIT :**
In [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx), it looks like VS already has an option to display exeptions, however,  when I'm selecting a method, it only shows the type, and the parameters of the method. But it doesn't show exceptions

Comment: if you mouseover a method, intellisense will tell you possible exceptions

Comment: Maybe i'm lazy, or just not that well versed in VS, but i usually just wait for the expression to be thrown then copy it from the error and put it in my try catch.

Comment: How can I enable intellisense ? When I hover a method I only see the method type, name and the parameters it can have.

Comment: intellisense will show you the possible exception only if exist the related xml tag before the method declaration, obviously not every method of BCL have this tag

Comment: @Jonesy it will only tell you that if a method has xml comments and the exception tag has been filled. Nothing forces developpers to use these, so they are very often missing.

Comment: side note:  Your `saveLog` is horrible.  Never just save the message of the exception; the message is practically worthless most of the time.  If logging an exception in this manner, call `ToString()` on it and save *that* result.  If your code example here is just shorthand for "do something with the exception" then please ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is, generally, to only add handling for exceptions you expect to occur during the run-time of your program.

If you're dealing with files, for example, handling the ***NotFoundException types makes sense. Proper coding will ensure things like ArgumentNullException don't happen, so that doesn't need handling, etc.

Comment: This answers how to handle exceptions, not how you can know which possible exceptions can be thrown.

Comment: @DavidS. The thing is, you mostly don't need to know (and not all libraries have proper/full documentation, so getting a comprehensive list is a pipe dream, anyway). So the code you write ensures that the functions you use get passed correct parameters, leaving you to just deal with the actual exceptional cases, like I explained above

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java, C# does not need to list your potential exeptions in the signature of your methods. This has some good sides and some bad sides. You just encountered one of the bad sides.

You cannot know what exception might be thrown unless

- The method you are calling is well documented with its potential exceptions listed (best case)
- You know the specific bad cases, run them and see what exceptions they create (bad case)
- You have no idea what could go wrong and log everything, modifying your catch every time something unexpected happens (worst case)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in feature to show this automatically but you put the caret somewhere in the method name and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>. The information shown here will be the same as that in your link, so it should show two exceptions for the `DownloadString` method.

Hovering over `DownloadString` won't necessarily show you the same information as clicking on the method name and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> (the latter showing you the exceptions being thrown by the method).